# How to Vectorise index insertion in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, vectorization

I have this problem with a very large data set which I can finished in Excel in less than a minute but it takes way too long on Python.

Objective: To give each row an ID based on information in column X and Y of the data set.

In Excel:

- Initialize counter to 1
- For each row i:

  - If both X = 0 and Y = 0, row ID = counter, followed by counter += 1
  - [edited] Else row ID = ID in the previous row.
- Next i

My pd dataframe is large.  Doing it in for loop takes more than an hour. I don't know how to vectorise my problem to avoid a for loop.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: could you show us the code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

To find an efficient Pandas solution, you should rephrase your problem. Your counter is essentially the number of the previous all-zero rows (plus 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [0,2,1,0,0,1,2,0], 
                   'Y': [0,2,1,3,0,0,1,2]})
df['counter'] = (((df.X==0) & (df.Y==0)).cumsum().shift() + 1)\
                  .fillna(1).astype(int)
#   X  Y  counter
#0  0  0        1
#1  2  2        2
#2  1  1        2
#3  0  3        2
#4  0  0        2
#5  1  0        3
#6  2  1        3
#7  0  2        3
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I was looking for a counter vector of [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2] given your dataset.  And your suggestion of using .cumsum() works perfectly.  Much appreciated.

Comment: According to your rules, the counter must increment _after_ the row of both zeros.

Comment: Counter increment happen after assigning counter to row ID.

Comment: Precisely. Initially, the counter is 1. It is assigned to the first matching row #0. Then it is incremented and becomes 2. Rows #1, 2,3, 4 are marked with the new value of the counter. That is how you describe it.

Comment: Oh ... my bad.  Apologies. I wrote the pseudo code wrong.  What I did in Excel was "Else Row ID (i) = Row ID (i - 1)".  Thanks for pointing this out.